# list-style-image: url(svg#id) in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, mozilla

I would set my svg element as

```
list-style-image: url(svg#id)
```

and point to figure by #id,
but it does not work

in this case all **root svg** element used as image, not part of it

It would be grate if i could separate my svg elements by defs and use after it like in

```
 <use xlink:href="#byId"/>
```

but in css:

```
 list-style-image: url(svg#id)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: How would the browser determine image size if you link to one part of the image only? Does this work in *any* browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the SVG stack technique, see [blogpost](http://simurai.com/post/20251013889/svg-stacks) and my modified [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mJQzE/3/) that shows how to use it in lists. Note that at the moment this only works in Firefox.